# Notification Volume Control

Tags: notifications, volume

One of the most annoying things about my phone is that the volume buttons adjust the ringer volume but not the notification volume.

Is there any way I could write a script or configure my phone so that the notifications volume is automatically the same as the ringer volume?

What about setting the volume buttons to set both the ringer and notifications volume?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings > Sound > Volumes`, then tick `Link ringtone and notifications volumes`.

If it's not there, you can use an Xposed module like GravityBox to achieve the same result. Just look in the `Media tweaks` menu.

Comment: Which version of Android would the first option be in?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it's been present on AOSP ROMs since 4.1.

Comment: It's automatically linked on KitKat aosp for sure (I just checked it). This option is implemented in some devices, but the OEM often overrides it, the tick box isn't present on the few devices I have to hand. If the option isn't there, then Xposed is the only way I can think of also.